# Jquery form submission is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I try to submit a form after my ajax request done. I do code like following. But when I click the button ajax request is go to and send 200 ok feedback. But after that form not submit. What is wrong on this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>

       $('document').ready(function(){
           $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        $.post('cart.php',{email:'email',pkgname:'pkgname'}).then(function(){
           $('form').submit();
        });
    });
       });


         </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="cart.php" method="post">
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure about what are you doing? As I see on button click you posting the data to `cart.php` and then again submitting the form to `cart.php`.. is that what you want to do?

Comment: i'm trying to do form submission when after my XHR request complete.. form does not submit twice. because my button type is not a submit button

Comment: I mean you are submitting form to same file `cart.php` and `$.post` request also pointed to same file

Comment: mmm.. My apologize for that...

Comment: @Nadishan please [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544300/when-form-has-submit-button-with-id-attribute-submit-does-not-work)

Comment: I found the answer for that!!!!! Please read the answers. i posted here that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here answer for my question. I don't know how is this possible??? :( My submit button id is the cause for my question. You never ever use #submit as a ID. It will be a problem!! This bugger wast my two days!!

So correct code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>

       $('document').ready(function(){
           $('#submit1').on('click',function(){
        $.post('cart.php',{email:'email',pkgname:'pkgname'}).then(function(){
           $('form').submit();
        });
    });
       });


         </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="cart.php" method="post">
            <input type="button" id="submit1" value="submit" />
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to build the `$.post` request like:

```
$.post('cart.php', {email:'email',pkgname:'pkgname'}, funtion(data){
   console.log(data);//return the data from server if anything echoed in cart.php file
})
```

where `data` contains what `cart.php` returns (i cannot understand why you are sending the form twice anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I update code as below and I think it is not getting response from sever I think u update this and check you will get your problem :

```js
 $('document').ready(function(){
           $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        $.post('cart.php',{email:'email',pkgname:'pkgname'}).success(function(data){
           $('form').submit();
        }).error(alert("Code has error"));
    });
       });
```

Comment: I've tried this code, When i click my button suddenly Code has error alert popup!! :O

Comment: Check in your sever side I think there may be problem in your cart.php, it is not returning right value.

Comment: Then what u think about the problem cause

Comment: Please read the answers here i am posted.. please see the answer section