# When form has submit button with id='submit' value, form submit does not work

Tags: javascript

While [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3at8d4b9/) works:

```
<form method="post" id="myform1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

document.getElementById("myform1").submit();
```

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqqgqb22/) does not work:

```
<form method="post" id="myform2">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

document.getElementById("myform2").submit();
```

Difference between them `submit` button has `id` in second code.

Why?

**Note**: while working [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542329/jquery-form-submission-is-not-working), I encountered situation

Answer (score 1):

the difference is the type of the button not the id

first example the type of the input is submit which submits forms. second example the type is button which doesn't submit forms

after OP editted question:

see that if you change the id of the submit button to basicly anything other than "submit" it works...

Answer (score 1):

This is noted on various sites such as this:

http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/dont-name-inputs-action-submit/

Having a button with `id='submit'` is also a known issue in jquery that hasn't been resolved

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1414

Presumably because the issue is outside of jquery's control and it'd require a hack.

I'd be interested to know exactly why.

Comment: But this is javascript

Comment: Yeah, I suspect the bug exists due to something underlying in javascript.